# Unable to download/read a file in documents path of my ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am using the below code to download a ebook from url and store into my device. While this works in emulator, in my ipad I am getting error saying file is not available. I am not able to read the file in the respective path of the device. please help..

```
NSString *urls =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://hungerin.com/?download_file=%@&order=%@&email=%@&key=%@", BookID, orderKey, email, downloadId];

                    NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urls]];

                    NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@""]];

                    NSString *filePathAppend = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"/testPubb.app/Documents/%@.epub",BookID];

                    NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePathAppend];

                    [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are getting the app document directory path is not correct. Try this:

```
NSString *urls =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://hungerin.com/?download_file=%@&order=%@&email=%@&key=%@", BookID, orderKey, email, downloadId];
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urls]];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.epub",BookID];
[pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks adeel but unable to read downloaded file from documents directory. File stored path is 
/var/mobile/containers/data/application/A5FF7EAB-F44B-4478-9A4A-DA75159D94CD/Documents/16.epub

Comment: Now tell me how you are reading a file from documents directory? Please share your code